# Reference to emplaced map values requires definition of class

Tags: c++

I need to change the way that I include headers in a larger project that I'm working on. I was able to simulate the errors I currently get with a smaller, single program.

By way of example, the following compiles:

```
#include <map>

class C;

class A {
public:
    C& add();
    std::map<int,C> Cmap;
    void dosomethingwithC();
};

class B {
public:
    A& add();
    std::map<int,A> Amap;
};

class C {
public:
    B& add();
    std::map<int,B> Bmap;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    auto& emplacedB = c.add();
    auto& emplacedA = emplacedB.add();
    auto& emplacedC = emplacedA.add();
    emplacedC.add();
    return 0;
}

C& A::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Cmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}

B& C::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Bmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    //auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    std::pair<const int,B>& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}

A& B::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Amap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;;
}

void A::dosomethingwithC()
{
    Cmap[3].add();
}
```

But, if I move `A`'s function definition closer to `A`, then the following does not compile:

```
#include <map>

class C;

class A {
public:
    C& add();
    std::map<int,C> Cmap;
    void dosomethingwithC();
};

C& A::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Cmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}

class B {
public:
    A& add();
    std::map<int,A> Amap;
};

class C {
public:
    B& add();
    std::map<int,B> Bmap;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    auto& emplacedB = c.add();
    auto& emplacedA = emplacedB.add();
    auto& emplacedC = emplacedA.add();
    emplacedC.add();
    return 0;
}

B& C::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Bmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    //auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    std::pair<const int,B>& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}

A& B::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Amap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;;
}

void A::dosomethingwithC()
{
    Cmap[3].add();
}
```

Even though `class C` is declared I get an error. The error explains that `std::pair` uses *undefined* `class C`.

What is the correct way to structure the headers and includes to make this compile?

Comment: There is a difference between *declaration* and *definition*. The **definition** of `C` is required when you create it (as in `A::add()`)

Comment: So I suppose headers including each other is not the way to go.

Comment: You have to do forwarding declaration in header, but cpp files would have both include.

Answer (score 1):

### Approach

- All the declarations must go in the headers and
- all the definitions go into the .cpp files.
- None of the headers include each other.

In this specific instance the error regarding the missing definition (for the `std::pair`, as part of the `std::map`) goes away if all the .cpp files include all the declarations. (A needs C, but C needs B)

So even though the error was for a missing definition, it could be solved by including a declaration. I'm not sure why and will post a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36667957/1460794).

### Solution

A.h

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

#include <map>

class C;

class A {
public:
    C& add();
    std::map<int,C> Cmap;
    void dosomethingwithC();
};

#endif
```

B.h

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h

#include <map>

class A;

class B {
public:
    A& add();
    std::map<int,A> Amap;
};

#endif
```

C.h

```
#ifndef C_h
#define C_h

#include <map>

class B;

class C {
public:
    B& add();
    std::map<int,B> Bmap;
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h" // also required here
#include "C.h"

C& A::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Cmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}


void A::dosomethingwithC()
{
    Cmap[3].add();
}
```

B.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h" // also required here

A& B::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Amap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;;
}
```

C.cpp

```
#include "A.h" // also required here
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

B& C::add()
{
    auto emplace_results = Bmap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(3),
        std::forward_as_tuple());
    auto pair_iterator = emplace_results.first;
    //auto& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    std::pair<const int,B>& emplaced_pair = *pair_iterator;
    auto& map_value = emplaced_pair.second;
    return map_value;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

int main()
{
    C c;
    auto& emplacedB = c.add();
    auto& emplacedA = emplacedB.add();
    auto& emplacedC = emplacedA.add();
    emplacedC.add();
    return 0;
}
```